# Is there an equivalent term for 'size' to go with 'spatial' and 'temporal'

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

I am trying to describe a dataset which has three measurements:

- The location of the particle (**spatial**)
- The change over time (**temporal**)
- The size of the particle (**UNKNOWN**)

Is there an equivalent term for size?

Furthermore, *spatiotemporal* appears to be a recognised term, or rarely *temporospatial*. Is there a way to fit size in, either with just one factor, or with both i.e. *Spatiosizal*, *size-temporal*, *spatiotemporal-size*?

Comment: What words have you tried or found that are close? Dimensional?

Comment: *spatial* covers size and position. Whether that solves your problem, or means you have a new one because you don't have a term specifically to location (there's a sense of *local* that means that, though it's maybe too overloaded) depends on what you need this term for.

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same page, spatial does not mean 'location' and temporal does not mean 'change over time'. Both spatial and temporal are classification terms that include those types of measurements. You have 2 spatial measurements and 1 temporal. If you switched to nouns you could be measuring: locality, scale/magnitude, delta(t).

Comment: Can you use scalar? _A quantity, such as mass, length, or speed, that is completely specified by its magnitude and has no direction_.

Comment: *Length* or *volume*.

Comment: the OP is asking for an adjective, though @aparente001

Comment: Daniel, what about the size is interesting for you?  For example, if it's volume, I think there is a word: volumetric.

Answer (score 3):

The size of the particle is the **volumetric** or **dimensional** measurement.

*From Oxford Living Dictionaries:*

> **[volumetric](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/volumetric)**
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1  Relating to the measurement of volume.

or

> **[dimensional](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dimensional)**
>
> ADJECTIVE
>
> 1  Relating to measurements or dimensions.

Sample from [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/volumetric):

> *‘Traditionally, two types of experiments have been used to study swelling behavior of cartilage, including measurements of* ***volumetric*** *swelling and* ***dimensional*** *swelling of cartilage.’*

*(emphasis added)*